# Using objects and classes of one form in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

The issue is quite complex. I have Main form which we shall call mainForm, another secondForm and thirdForm. secondForm opens inside a panel in mainForm using a method which is under the class of mainForm.  I want to open thirdForm inside the panel of mainForm but through a click event occurring in secondForm  using the same method which is under mainForm's class. This means that l have to call that method, but l want to do it without altering it's declation to static' Anyone with a good way of achieving that.The method is right below.

```
public void OpenChildForm(Form ChildForm)
    {
        if (activeForm != null)
        {
            activeForm.Close();
            activeForm = ChildForm;
            ChildForm.TopLevel = false;
            ChildForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            ChildForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panelChildForm.Controls.Add(ChildForm);
            panelChildForm.Tag = ChildForm;
            ChildForm.BringToFront();
            ChildForm.Show();
        }
         else
        {
            activeForm = ChildForm;
            ChildForm.TopLevel = false;
            ChildForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            ChildForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panelChildForm.Controls.Add(ChildForm);
            panelChildForm.Tag = ChildForm;
            ChildForm.BringToFront();
            ChildForm.Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `secondForm` you can get a reference to `mainForm` via the [ParentForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform) property:

```
// in ...secondForm ...
mainForm mf = this.ParentForm as mainForm;
if (mf != null) {
    thirdForm tf = new thirdForm();
    mf.OpenChildForm(tf);
}
```